# How do I get rid of the TLE error in Python?

Tags: python

When am working with a Python code involving for loop, often am getting TLE (time limit exceed) error.

How can I overcome that error?

For example: in using a for loop of range n, if the loop goes to really very large value say, 10^8 am getting that error. Is there any efficient way which can replace for loops for faster execution?

Comment: If you're talking about execution on some of the online competition websites, check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/

Comment: Instead of trying to find a faster way to do 100 million things, try to find an algorithm that doesn't need to do 100 million things.

Answer (score 0):

Break statement can be used in some situations to solve TLE error.